# What's the longest scheduled helicopter flight?

Tags: air-travel, factoids, helicopters

I'm looking for the longest scheduled commercial helicopter route in the world. It could be seasonal but should be recurring and anyone should be able to purchase tickets for the route.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3070/18374

Answer (score 3):

There is a [scheduled helicopter route](https://helity.es/index.php?r=booking%2Fcreate) from **Malaga** (Spain) to **Ceuta** (Spain, Africa mainland).

There are two more (as I write) flights today:

> Flight no. HTY242 departs 10 Feb. 2020 at 18:35 arriving 19:05
>
> Flight no. HTY210 departs 10 Feb. 2020 at 21:25 arriving 21:55

The distance is 71 miles (114 kilometers).

Answer (score 2):

Vas'kovo airport of Arkhangelsk has [scheduled helicopter flights](http://www.2aoao.ru/shedule.php) to Shoina at a total distance of ~420 km:

[image: Schedule]

The last column is price (С for plane, В for helicopter).

I assume same route can be flown with either plane or helicopter, what does that depend on, I know not. Btw, it costs slightly less than $300 one way. I'm yet to try that, hope to do that one day.

[image: Шойна]

Answer (score 0):

Try https://blade.flyblade.com/ 
According to their website, flights from KJFK to Manhattan, Monday through Friday, 3:00 PM to 7:00 PM local times costs $195 per person with one carry-on.

Or

https://helijet.com/2015/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Helijet-Schedule-Information-FW19-20.pdf
Straight line distance is 53 Nautical Miles (98 km). Considering obstacle and airspace clearance, it might be more expeditious for them to take a slightly longer route than direct.

Or

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_helicopter_airlines

You seem to have a strong interest in helicopters. Have you thought of saving the money you would spend on random flights. Instead, putting that money into lessons. You might not get to finish your license on that amount of money. But, it would be an experience you will never forget. If you do get the license, it is something you will have for life (barring it being invalidated for violations of aviation regulations or safety protocols).

Time in a Robinson R-22 would cost you $250-300 an hour including fuel, maintenance, etc. An instructor would cost you an additional $50-100 an hour. You could solo (fly on your own without an instructor) in as little as 10 hours.

Comment: Dean, while this is valuable advice, it does not answer the question at all. With this kind of questions we are looking for 'location' to 'location' and 'so many times per day/week'.

Comment: @Willeke - Does that help?

Comment: Are you quite sure you retain a pilot's license "for life"? AFAIK you need regular flying hours and assessment. The idea that you do not pilot a helicopter for 20 years and then be able to fly a next-generation machine is absurd.

Comment: I'd say it is still not really an answer as intended but I leave it to the community for now.

Comment: In the U.S., you retain the pilot certificate for life unless it is taken away by the FAA. However, you can not exercise the privileges of Pilot in Command of a General Aviation, single-pilot certified, personal, private light aircraft unless you meet medical requirements and have had an official Flight Review in the past 24 calendar months. If one or both of those stipulations are not met, you can still fly with another qualified pilot acting as PIC. That is the very simplified answer. There are further stipulations on what type of aircraft you can fly and at what times and conditions.